# What does the MATLAB error "scalar structure required for this assignment" refer to in this statement?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, cell-array

I have a structure, `space_averaged_data`, which has a member `Ps` that is defined as a cell array with a variable length. I assign values to this cell array after creating the structure as shown below (I've omitted the other structure fields for clarity):

```
Ps = cell( 1, num_p );
for p = 1:length(Ps)
    Ps{p} = rand( 150, 1000 );
end

space_averaged_data = struct( 'Ps', cell( 1, length(Ps) ) );

for p = 1:length(Ps)
    space_averaged_data.Ps{p} = mean( Ps{p}, 2 );
end
```

If the value of `num_p` is 1 (i.e., the cell array isn't an array), everything works just fine. If the value of `num_p` is greater than 1, however, I get the following error:

```
Scalar structure required for this assignment.
Error in:
    space_averaged_data.Ps{p} = mean( Ps{p}, 2 );
```

**What is the non-scalar structure in this assignment?** I have no idea what the error is referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `1x5` `struct` array.  To quote the [`struct` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html):

> If `value` is a cell array, then `s` is a structure array with the same dimensions as `value`. Each element of `s` contains the corresponding element of `value`.

Since the second argument in the expression `struct( 'Ps', cell( 1, length(Ps) ) )` is a `1x5` `cell`, the output `struct` will be a `1x5` `struct` array, and the proper assignment in the `for`-loop will be

```
space_averaged_data(p).Ps = mean( Ps{p}, 2 );
```

To get the behavior you desire, wrap the second argument in `{}` to make it a `1x1` `cell` array:

```
space_averaged_data = struct( 'Ps', {cell( 1, length(Ps) )} );
```

and the `for`-loop should work as expected.